# R socketConnection/make.socket(): any way to keep listen()ing?

Tags: sockets, r

[Disclaimer: my knowledge of sockets is very rusty, and I'm just getting into R, so if I missed something completely obvious, please point it out!]

If I understand the (sparsely-documented) R functions for creating and managing sockets, namely `socketConnection` and `make.socket`, it appears that when creating a server socket (`server=TRUE`), the moral equivalent of the following is carried out:

```
s = socket(yada yada);
listen(s, ...);
s2 = accept(s, ...);
close(s, ...);
```

and now I can work with `s2` but can't loop to deal with a backlog of incoming connections to `s`. Is this more-or-less right? Is there any way to keep listening and continue to deal with additional incoming connections after handling the first?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to know the answer to this one too! ...but in the meantime I can at least suggest a work-around with some limitations:

If you can know HOW MANY clients will connect, then the following should work.

On the server:

```
n=2         # Number of clients
port=22131

slist=vector('list',n)
# Connect to all clients
for(i in 1:n) slist[i] <- socketConnection('localhost', port=port, server=TRUE)

# Wait for a client to send data, returns the client index 
repeat {
  avail <- which( socketSelect(slist) )[[1]]
  # ...then read and process data, rinse, repeat...
}
```

On each client:

```
port=22131
# Connect to server
s <- socketConnection('localhost', port=port)
# ...then send data...
writeLines(c('foo', 'bar'), s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately I don't know ahead of time how many clients could be connecting simultaneously, although I may adapt your code to recycle connections in a 'socket pool' that can support up to N clients at once.

Answer (score -3):

No, you can touch the back-log on `s1`.

---

Window 1:

```
$ R
s1 = socketConnection(server=T,port=12345)
s2 = socketConnection(server=T, port=98765)
```

Window 2:

```
$ nc localhost 12345
If ever I should leave you, it wouldn't be in springtime
Knowing how in spring I'm bewitched by you so
oh no not in springtime, summer, winter, or fall
no never could I leave you at all
```

Window 3:

```
$ nc localhost 98765
for Hitler and Germany
Deutschland is happy and gay
we're marching to a faster pace
look out, here comes the Master Race!
```

Window 1:

```
readLines(s1,1)
# "if ever I should leave you, it wouldn't be in springtime"
readLines(s2,1)
# "for Hitler and Germany"
readLines(s1,1)
# "knowing how in spring I'm bewitched by you so"
```

Comment: downvoter ... are you saying this is wrong? Or just don't like my taste in musical theatre?

Comment: Let me tell you why the downvote: "Hitler and Germany"..      Why  can't you change it to something nicer?

Comment: For everyone who keeps flagging this, please note that the above are lyrics from ["Springtime for Hitler"](https://genius.com/Mel-brooks-springtime-for-hitler-lyrics) from ["The Producers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Producers_(1967_film))/

Comment: Regardless of the origin of this lyrics, it endorses violent racism and is absolutely unnecessary for answering the question anway.